# How to refresh controller from a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is the demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/atZZXM6YVYQL0SilpWxq?p=preview

In a table, I display each value of my collection, everything is fine. But when I remove one element in the list, the controller isn't refreshed. I choose a directive in order to add and remove an edit line after each element. I needed `jQuery` for that but maybe there is a more elegant way to achieve it. I suppose a `$watch` or `$broadcast` is missing.

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items" item-directive="item"></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>{{getTotal()}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### AngularJS

```
app.directive("itemDirective", function($compile){
  var trLine = '<tr><td>{{itemDirective.name}}</td><td>{{itemDirective.value}}</td>'
          +'<td><button ng-click="edit()">Edit</button></td>'
          +'<td><button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button></td>'
          +'<td><button ng-click="removeFromController()">Remove from controller</button></td>'
          +'</tr>';
  var trEditLine = '<tr class="editLine"><td style="background: #E6E6E6"><div>'
          +'<button ng-click="done();">Done</button>'
          +'<button  ng-click="cancel();">Cancel</button></div></td>'
        +'</tr>';
    return {
        template: trLine,
        replace: false,
        scope: {
          itemDirective: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.edit = function() {
            if(!element.edited) {
              element.edited = true;
              element.after($compile(trEditLine)(scope));
            }
          };
          scope.cancel = function() {
            element.edited = false;
            $(".editLine").remove();
          };
          scope.done = function() {
            element.edited = false;
            $(".editLine").remove();
          };
          scope.remove = function() {
            element.remove();
          };
        }
    };
});
```

This will remove the line as expected but the total doesn't change.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: you are only deleting the dom element using jquery instead you should remove item from items

Comment: yes, I found this way to remove the line but I don't know how I can remove the item inside the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would provide `removeFromController()` method to directive (since you use isolated scope) and  write `ng-repeat` like:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items" item-directive="item" invoke="removeFromController()">
```

Now directive:

```
scope: {
      itemDirective: '=',
      invoke: '&'
    },
```

and `trLine`:

```
var trLine = '<tr><td>{{itemDirective.name}}</td><td>{{itemDirective.value}}</td>'
          +'<td><button ng-click="edit()">Edit</button></td>'
          +'<td><button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button></td>'
          +'<td><button ng-click="invoke()">Remove from controller</button></td>'
          +'</tr>';
```

See edited <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4NQzIghXpJhl8sOMEFFW?p=preview)**</kbd>